# how to group the functions in class

Tags: function, class

i am new to PHP how to group functions inside a class and use it in other pages to reduce typing **this is for single page what if i use multiple pages with pageination**
this is my coding

```
<?php

include ('conn.php');
class sel
{
function sell()
{
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$id=$_POST['id'];   
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);   
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$result = $myDBObject -> select('*', 'admin', 'username = "'.$username.'" and
  password ="'.$password.'"');
$x = $rdata['id'];
echo $x;
 $_SESSION['username'] =$id;
echo $_SESSION['username'];
if(! $rdata)
{
echo "Enter your username and password correctly";
}
else
{

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     document.location="list.php";
     </script>';

}
}
}
}
$myDBObject = new sel();
$myDBObject->sell();
?>
```

and my connection.php code is

```
<?php
class DBConnect
{
private $host = 'localhost';
private $user = 'root';
private $pass = '';
private $db = 'enquiry';

public function __construct(){
$conn = mysql_connect($this -> host, $this -> user, $this -> pass);
$sql = mysql_select_db($this -> db, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
private function select($select, $table, $where){
$sql = "select ".$select." from ".$table." where ".$where;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
return $rdata = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

} 
$myDBObject = new DBConnect();
$myDBObject->__construct();
$myDBObject->select($select, $table, $where);
?>
```

if i did like this i get this error what did i do wrong in code

```
Fatal error: Call to private method DBConnect::select() from context '' in C:\xampp\htdocs
\Raj\cform\conn.php on line 23
```

Comment: Your efforts have been so thorough that you've not even defined a single function!

Comment: I don't understand what the question is really asking either. On a completely unrelated note, you've opened yourself up to some pretty terrible SQL injection attacks with the username and password coming from post!

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili yup i am new to programming

Comment: @MattFletcher i want to use function and class for this code and group them thats my question

Comment: Also, I don't think you quite understand what classes are for- they're definitely not for re-using code in this kind of context, that's for sure. Probably best to not worry about OOP at the moment (running before walking!) And I still don't understand which bit it is that you want to group together... What are you re-using? The database connection code or the login validation? ...or something else?

Comment: @MattFletcher database connection code i wanna reuse

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use database class as mentioned below

```
class DBConnect
{
private $host = 'localhost';
private $user = 'user';
private $pass = 'pass';
private $db = 'mydb';

public function __construct(){
    $conn = mysql_connect($this -> host, $this -> user, $this -> pass);
    $sql = mysql_select_db($this -> db, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
}

// select query
private function select($select, $table, $where){
    $sql = "select ".$select." from ".$table." where ".$where;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return $rdata = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

// update query
private function update($update, $table, $where){
    // code here
}
}
```

When required, create object of the class and call functions as below

```
require 'dbConnect.php';    // assuming, you have included the database class in this file
$myDBObject = new DBConnect();
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);   // mysql escaping
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);   // mysql escaping
// select required data
$result = $myDBObject -> select('*', 'admin', 'username = "'.$username.'" and password = "'.$password.'"');
```

The function described in the class above are for demonstration purpose. You can include other functions in the class along with data escaping functionality.

FYI: `mysql` is deprecrated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Answer (score -2):

//  Hi,

```
class ClassName {
    static function funcName1(){
        funcBody1;
    }

    static function funcName2(){
        funcBody2;
    }
}
```

//  to use functions juste do :

```
ClasseName::funcName1();
ClasseName::funcName2();
```

Comment: This has (code-breaking!) spelling mistakes- and the `funcBody1;` bits are quite misleading as they're not commented... but non-code bits... are... commented :P. Also doesn't say where to include the code, or what it will return, or how the OP will actually use it. Plus it doesn't address why oh why anyone would create a class full of static functions. Just an unnecessary many extra steps. I think that's enough of me berating you for your answer, sorry ha :)